# Accessing objects with OneToOne relationship to a model in Django

Tags: python, django, orm

I have the following models, which are dependent on `django.contrib.auth.models.User`.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='teacher')
    ...

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='student')
    ...
```

How can I get a `QuerySet` of `User` objects who are related to `Teacher`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.objects.exclude(teacher=None)
```